# ScrollTop not working correct with parallax effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I'm implemented a pure css parallax effect in my website. Next step was to implement the scrollTop functionality the site is a one page layout.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: $target.offset().top
    }, 2000);  
  });
});
```

With this I get a strange behavior:

1. initial start, click on anchor -> it scroll to the div
2. click on another anchor -> it does what it does not what it should

here the jsFiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/5pwctshp/2/

after some research could it be the overflow property that trigger the bug/problem?

Thank's in advance

Comment: check with my answer. [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528922/parallax-effect-calculate-child-offset-to-parent-on-scroll/39529372#39529372)

Comment: thank's for your response but could you explain something? i try to understand the problem :-) and not copy and paste the solution